# What is the best approach for solving sporadic Oracle performance problems on large systems?

Tags: oracle, performance, concurrency, view

I have a case where a specific query on a complex View on a large database at a customer site often runs fast (4 or 5 seconds), and sometimes very slow (7 minutes). The View is used to summarise all customer database activity in the last couple of minutes, and typically produces less than 1000 rows.

Only once have I been able to reproduce the problem, connecting to the customer database and running the query they use. All other times I have tried to reproduce the problem it has run fast, even during peak periods of user activity.

The query also always runs fast on the customer testing database, but has this sporadic performance problem on their production database.

The production database produces thousands of transactions every hour and has many users. Their test database does not.

I suspect the Problem is related to what else is happening on their System, rather than the View itself, but don't know how to test or prove that, or where to start looking.

What might it be?

Concurrency Issues? .. The View is only used to read data, never for writing.

I havent included the code for the View as i doubt that will help.

Any suggestions as to where I might look or what I might do to find the reason for the sporadic performance issues and fix it?

Comment: how about creating a materialized view based on the view and refreshing that?  Definitely better performance but does not address the underlying cause.

Comment: @kevinsky, would a materialized view not have a performance impact on every single insert/update?

Comment: @Ralf It would not have any more impact than querying the view.  In this case a materialized view is a cached copy of the data, querying is fast, it is used as read only but it is out of date as far as the last refresh time. Inserts and updates don't enter into it.

Comment: @kevinsky The view is a summary view. If we assume it contains aggregations and there are millions of inserts/updates between each select of the view, then each insert/update would have the addtl. cost to update the materialized view. Would it not?

Comment: @Ralf If you use the fast refresh method, which you probably could not due to the complicated nature of the join, then changes to the table are written to log tables which Oracle creates and manages.  I was proposing a scheduled complete refresh which is no more intensive than querying the view

Comment: @kevinsky OK, got it.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. The View is live. It is typically run looking at transactions since one or two minutes in the past. Not sure that would work with a materialized view, which would have to be refreshed every few minutes. It is also a UNION ALL of 5 relatively complex queries, each of which is an UNPIVOT on various tables.

Comment: On second thoughts .. i think i might indeed do a test with a materialized view .. to see if that helps. If I restrict it to the last few minutes of transactions and run it in the background, that would indeed make queries run later almost instantaneous. If the customer never needs to look further into the past, then it'll be worth a shot. I'll ask them.

Comment: Latest status is that the problem hasn't appeared for a while. It's must be something in their system.